# Webpack 2.x module resolution extension priority

Tags: webpack, file-extension

I have `foo.js` and `foo.ts` in the same directory, where I `import './foo'`, it seems that `foo.js` is resolved. Is it possible to change this to prefer `*.ts` files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply put `.ts` before `.js` in your [`resolve.extensions`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve-extensions) configuration.

For example:

```
resolve: {
  extensions: ['.ts', '.js', '.json']
}
```